# Incompatible type for argument for sqrt() in C

Tags: c

I'm new to threads, and I can't see where my error is. Just started to learn them today. Can anyone see whats the error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <math.h>

double somatorio = 0;

void *raizQuadrada(void *numero)
{
  somatorio+=sqrt(numero);
}

int main()
{
  pthread_t thread1, thread2;

  for(int a = 1;a<=500000; a++)
  {
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, raizQuadrada, (double *) &a);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, raizQuadrada, (double *) &a+500000);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
  }

  printf("Resultado: %f\n", somatorio);

  exit(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Terminal output:

```
pth-ex6.c: In function ‘raizQuadrada’: pth-ex6.c:11:19: error:
incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘sqrt’    somatorio+=sqrt(numero);
                   ^~~~~~ In file included from /usr/include/features.h:424:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:27,
                 from pth-ex6.c:1: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:143:1: note: expected
‘double’ but argument is of type ‘void *’  __MATHCALL (sqrt,,
(_Mdouble_ __x));
```

Comment: The error says it pretty clearly: _expected ‘double’ but argument is of type ‘void *’_ You need to cast the `void *` back to `double *` then dereference to `double`.

Comment: Aside: `(double *) &a` and `(double *) &a+500000` look suspicious, when `int a` is a loop counter.

Comment: @WeatherVane They don't look suspicious, they look guilty.

Comment: `somatorio+=sqrt(numero);`?  From multiple threads?  Read this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition

Answer (score 0):

if you look in math.h [documentation](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/math.h/sqrt), you can see that sqrt takes double as input

```
double sqrt(double arg);
```

but you are trying to pass in `void *`

It so happens that its stated clearly in the error message -

```
from pth-ex6.c:1: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:143:1: note: 
expected
‘double’ but argument is of type ‘void *’  __MATHCALL (sqrt,,
(_Mdouble_ __x));
```

if you are new to coding - one of the most useful things to learn is to read the error output :-)